# Remember me doesn't work with www?

Tags: login, urls

On my Wordpress installation, "Remember me" works (tested in multiple browsers with multiple people) when the URL is entered as http://foobar.com. If the URL is entered as http://www.foobar.com, "Remember me" never works.

I've searched Google and haven't found any answers to "Remember me" being dependent on having www or not, just things like cookie issues or that it works in one browser and not another.

How can that be fixed?

Comment: Are you talking about the little checkbox on the login screen? What WordPress version? Have you disabled your plugins and switched to a core-bundled theme (twenty-something)?

Comment: Thanks - it's version 4.0. I just tried deactivating every plugin and switching to Twenty Fourteen. I see the same behavior.

Comment: Does your site display with both www and without it? Or does the site redirect (which is what really should be happening)?

Comment: It's redirecting and only shows without www. When you go to www.foobar.com/wp-admin, the URL changes to 
foobar.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.foobar.com%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1. After logging in, you're taken to foobar.com/wp-admin

Comment: How does your www redirect work?